# PHP login/logout and register

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, logout

I have attempted to create a simple form with register and login/logout page. But it keeps giving me errors. Please help.

**Notice**: Undefined index: username in ..path/to/index.php on line 4

**Notice**: Undefined index: password in ..path/to/index.php on line 5

**Warning**: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ..path/toindex.php:4) in ..path/to/index.php on line 8

Login.php

```
session_start();

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
    if($username && $password)
    {
        header( 'Location: index.php' );
    }
    else
    {
        function index()
        {
            echo "<form action='' method='post'>"
                ."Username:<input type='text' name='username' size='30'>"
                ."Password:<input type='password' name='password' size='20'>"
                ."<input type='submit' value='Login' name='login'/>"
                ."</form>";
        }
        function login()
        {
            $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
            $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

            if ($username=="")
            {
                die("<br /> You Forgot to type in your Username!");
            }
            if ($password=="")
            {
                die("<br /> You Forgot to type in your Password!");
            }

            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost" ,"root" , "root" ,"user");
            // check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
            {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            } 

            $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            $user = $row['username'];
            if($username != $user)
            {
                die("<br />Username is wrong!<br /> ");
            }

            $real_password = $row['password'];
            if($password != $real_password)
            {
                die("<br />Your password is wrong!<br /> ");
            }

            $_SESSION['username']=$username;
            $_SESSION['password']=$password;

            header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
        }

        if (isset($_REQUEST['login']))
        {
            login();
        }
        else
        {
            index();
        }
    }
?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header( 'Location: login.php' ) ;
?>
```

Register.php

```
<?php
session_start();

echo "<h2 style='padding-left: 10px'>Register A User :</h2>"
    ."<form action='' method='post'>"
    ."Username :<input type='text' name='user' size='30'>"
    ."Password :<input type='password' name='password' size='20'>"
    ."<input type='submit' value='Register' name='register' />";

if (isset($_REQUEST['register']))
{
    $username = $_REQUEST['user'];
    $pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];

    if ($username=="")
    {
        die("<br /> You Forgot to type in the Username for the user ! <br /> ");
    }
    if ($pass=="")
    {
        die("<br />You Forgot to type in the Password for the user !<br />");
    }
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost" ,"root" , "root" ,"user");
            // check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
            {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            } 
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$pass') ");
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $password = $_SESSION['password'];
        if(!$username && !$password)
        {
            header( 'Location: login.php' ) ;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<h3>Welcome to My Webpage</h3>";
        }
?>
```

Comment: Seems that variables `$username` and `$password` are not known by `Register.php`

Comment: You need to check if the variables are set first. Try `if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
}`, same goes for password on all files.

Comment: Your errors and notices are being sent as part of the response, which as a result triggers the warning. Send the errors to a log file instead.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php/8028987#8028987

Answer (score 0):

Those notices are caused by the following:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
```

You don't know that the $_SESSION['username'] or $_SESSION['password'] values exist, so you should not attempt access. Fixing that, will fix the "Cannot modify header information" warning.

There are a couple ways to address this problem.

1. You can use suppress the error using the @ symbol:

   ```
   $username = @$_SESSION['username'];
   $password = @$_SESSION['password'];
   ```
2. You can turn off notices via ini_set:

   ```
   ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
   ```

   or by setting the error_reporting setting in you php.ini to 32759, the value returned by E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE.
3. You can test to see that the session variables are not empty before initializing them:

   ```
   if( !empty($_SESSION['username']) ) {
       $username = $_SESSION['username'];
   }

   if( !empty($_SESSION['password']) ) {
       $password = $_SESSION['password'];
   }
   ```

   Again, use the empty function to make sure that $username and $password have been set in your conditional check:

   ```
   if( !empty($username) && !empty($password) )
   ```

   or define the $username and $password variables before attempting to use them:

   ```
   $username = null;
   $password = null;

   if( !empty($_SESSION['username']) ) {
       $username = $_SESSION['username'];
   }

   if( !empty($_SESSION['password']) ) {
       $password = $_SESSION['password'];
   }
   ```

Regarding the use of error suppression, as much as possible, you want to avoid it. Suppressing errors, even simple notices, robs you of useful insight into what your code is actually doing. A simple notice may hint at a more sinister logical error, and suppressing it can sometimes make your life a living hell. I've lost quite a bite of hair due to rogue @ symbols.